# How can I determine if my KDE Desktop is in lock screen state from command line?

Tags: linux, x11, desktop, kde-plasma

I have a program run on the background that simply take a screenshot every N seconds.

eg:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
  take-screenshot
  sleep 10
done
```

What I want to achieve is only take screenshot if screen is not locking.
eg:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
  if ! screen-is-locking; then
    take-screenshot
    sleep 10
  fi
done
```

How can I determine if my desktop is locking in command line?

Comment: [this should answer your question](https://superuser.com/questions/820596/kde-screen-lock-log)

Comment: You can monitor lock screen state changes with D-Bus: https://superuser.com/a/820619

Answer (score 7):

According to [this link](https://superuser.com/a/820619) provided by fellow comments under this question, I got a solution or workaround for my question, it works well under 5.4.58-1-MANJARO KDE Plasma (other DE might have different ways according to that answer's statement).

There's a method in dbus service which well fit my need:

```sh
#/bin/sh

is_screen_locking()
{
  if dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver --type=method_call --print-reply /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive | grep 'boolean true' > /dev/null; then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}



if is_screen_locking; then
   echo 'screen is locking'
else
   echo 'screen is not locking'
fi
```